# qt.qpa.xcb: X server does not support XInput 2 opening paraFoam

Tags: qt, paraview, openfoam

qt.qpa.xcb: X server does not support XInput 2                                                                                                                                                                     failed to get the current screen resources                                                                                                                                                                         QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-joaomota'                                                                                                                                     qt.qpa.gl: QXcbConnection: Failed to initialize GLX                                                                                                                                                                ERROR: In /home/ubuntu/OpenFOAM/ThirdParty-dev/ParaView-5.6.3/VTK/Rendering/OpenGL2/vtkOpenGLRenderWindow.cxx, line 736                                                                                            vtkGenericOpenGLRenderWindow (0x7fffe6033a70): GLEW could not be initialized.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         I/O    : uncollated

I'm getting all this when trying to open ParaView

Comment: ParaView or paraFOAM ?